# How do I safely use a polymorphic model in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, polymorphic-associations

I understand it's a best practice to define your models in a migration if you are manipulating model data during a migration. When I try to build_other with a polymorphic association, however, the polymorphic_type attribute is getting namespaced the model to the migration I've declared it in, leading the resulting data set to not really be associated.

Basically, I end up with addresses that have addressable_type set to "RemoveAddressColumnsFromEmployeesTable::Employee" instead of just "Employee".

I can fix this by explicitly setting the addressable_type and addressable_id, but is this the only way to handle this encapsulation?

```
class RemoveAddressColumnsFromEmployeesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :inverse_of => :addressable
  end

  class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :address
  end

 def up
   Employee.all.each do |e|
     address                = e.build_address
     address.street_address = e.street_address
     address.apt_num        = e.apt_num
     address.city           = e.city
     address.state          = e.state
     address.zip            = e.zip
     e.save
   end

   remove_column :employees, :street_address
   remove_column :employees, :apt_num
   remove_column :employees, :city
   remove_column :employees, :state
   remove_column :employees, :zip
 end

 def down
   add_column :employees, :street_address, :string
   add_column :employees, :apt_num,        :string
   add_column :employees, :city,           :string
   add_column :employees, :state,          :string
   add_column :employees, :zip,            :string                                                                                                             

   Employee.all.each do |e|
     e.street_address = e.address.street_address
     e.apt_num        = e.address.apt_num
     e.city           = e.address.city
     e.state          = e.address.state
     e.zip            = e.address.zip
     e.address = nil
     e.save
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: This was asked quite a while ago. Did you ever figure out a better way? I want to post the same question but if I do, it will be marked as a duplicate of yours.

Comment: Anybody found decision for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found decision that arranged me. In you case this means replacing polymorphic association on the next one:

```
  class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address, :foreign_key => :addressable_id, :conditions => {:addressable_type => 'Employee'}
  end

  class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
  end
```